# Conflict between siunitx and hyperxmp?

Tags: errors, siunitx, incompatibility, hyperxmp

When I typset this MWE:

```
% arara: lualatex: {synctex: yes, shell: yes}
\documentclass[%
                fontsize=10pt, %
                twoside,%
                DIV=calc, %
                a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[free-standing-units=true,overwrite-functions=true]{siunitx}

\usepackage{hyperxmp}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
s_{ij} =\int_a^b {s_i \left( t \right) \phi _j ^{\ast} \left( t \right)dt},\quad \begin{aligned}
i&=1,\ldots, M\\
j&=1,\ldots, N
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

there is an error in the second run. The error doesn't exist if I don't load the hyperxmp package.  Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: When you use `free-standing-units=true`, `siunitx` will redefine the TeX primitive `\day` to the SI unit for day. The `hyperxmp` package (and many others, actually) expects that `\day` is the TeX primitive, not something else, thus the error. And that's why `siunitx` defines the units only inside its own commands, so that this type of conflict doesn't happen. If you remove `free-standing-units=true` the error will go away.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik: Perfect! Can you put your solution in an answer? In this way, I could vote up. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hyperxmp` package inserts some code at `\end{document}` that does `\ifnum\day<10 <do things>\fi`, which expects `\day` to be a number. `\day` is a TeX primitive register which holds the number of the current day, so everything's fine so far.

However, when you use `free-standing-units=true` and `overwrite-functions=true` (a dangerous combination), `siunitx` will redefine the TeX primitive `\day` to the SI unit for day. But the `hyperxmp` package (and many others, actually) expects that `\day` is the TeX primitive, not something else. And when it does `\ifnum\day<10` it finds something that is not a number and TeX says `Missing number, treated as zero`. And that's why `siunitx` defines the units only inside its own commands, so that this type of conflict doesn't happen.

If you remove `free-standing-units=true` the error will go away. Alternatively you can set `overwrite-functions=false`, so that the only functions `siunitx` will define "free-standing" are the ones whose names are not yet taken, so `\day` will remain being TeX's `\day`, while `\metre`, for example, will be `siunitx`'s.

Comment: A very complete explanation. Many thanks.